# St. Robert Bellarmine on the Suspension of Public Masses

Tags: catholicism, mass, daniel, alphonsus-liguori

In his *Dignity and Duties of the Priest, or Selva*, St. Alphonsus Liguori writes:

> Hence the devil has always sought to deprive the world of the Mass by means of the heretics, constituting them precursors of Antichrist, whose first efforts shall be to abolish the holy sacrifice of the altar, and, according to the prophet Daniel, in punishment of the sins of men, his efforts shall be successful: *And strength was given him against the continual sacrifice because of sins. (Dan. viii. 20.)*

I recall having read somewhere a while back, that St. Robert Bellarmine interpreted the aforementioned verse in Daniel as meaning that (all) *public Masses* would be suspended for a time.

Can anyone point me to where I may find this in St. Robert Bellarmine's writings, as well as to what else he may have had to say on Daniel 8:12?